# Import excel in laravel Array key

Tags: excel, laravel, import

I am trying to upload the file but when I give import I get the following error Undefined array key "idEvento"

When I handle it by number that I start from scratch I do not get any error and insert into the database

Event Model

```
    <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Eventos extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'nombre',
        'idEvento',
        'idSede',
        'inicio',
        'fin',
        'idModalidad',
        'cupo',
        'valor',
    ];
}
```

Import data function

```
public function importData(Request $request){

        $file = $request->file('documento');

        $validator = Validator::make(
            array(
                'file' => $file,
            ),
            array(
                'file' => 'file|max:5000|mimes:xlsx,xls',
            )
        );

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return Redirect::to('conferencia/import');
       }

        $import = new EventosImport();
        Excel::import($import, request()->file('documento'));
        return view('conferencias.import', ['numRows'=>$import->getRowCount()]);
        //return redirect()->to(url('conferencia'));
    }
```

Event import code

```
    <?php

namespace App\Imports;

use App\Models\Eventos;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;

class EventosImport implements ToModel, WithHeadingRow
{
    private $numRows = 0;
    /**
    * @param array $row
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
    */
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        ++$this->numRows;
        return new Eventos([
            'nombre' => $row['nombre'],
            'idEvento' => $row['idEvento'],
            'idSede' => $row['idSede'],
            'inicio' => \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date::excelToDateTimeObject($row['inicio']),
            'fin' => \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date::excelToDateTimeObject($row['fin']),
            'idModalidad' => $row['idModalidad'],
            'cupo' => $row['cupo'],
            'valor' => $row['valor'],
        ]);
    }

    public function getRowCount(): int
    {
        return $this->numRows;
    }
}
```

Image of the excel[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cqx6.png)

Answer (score 0):

it´s better than you use your function import in your controller instead of in your model. To read excel use sometimes similary to:

```
$data = Excel::load($path, function($reader) {})->get();

        if(!empty($data) && $data->count()){

            foreach ($data->toArray() as $key => $value) {

                if(!empty($value)){

                    foreach ($value as $v) {        

                        $insert[] = ['title' => $v['title'], 'description' => $v['description']];

                    }
                }
            }

            if(!empty($insert)){
                Item::insert($insert);
                return back()->with('success','Insert Record successfully.');
            }
        }
```